# Access List Boxes

Tags: vba, ms-access, duplicates, listbox-control

Multiple List Boxes ControlSource is set to a field name. I want my form to show the current data for this list box, but NOT show the same data on other list boxes (all show the same data, as joined by the same ControlSource) ie; listbox1 to show data from Row1 of Table, listbox2 to show data from Row2 of Table, listbox3...Table Row3,etc.
How to write each listbox different, while all are connected to the same field?

Each Listbox shows the same data from the same row in the field.

Comment: The language you are using matters a whole lot here. Tag it.

Comment: Language is Access VBA.

Comment: Couple of questions here. How many listboxes are there?  How many rows of data do you want to display? (is it the same as the amount of listboxes?) Whats the purpose of these listboxes? (maybe there's a better solution) Can you mock up an example of the data and example of the output you want to see?

Comment: Actually, they are Textboxes. Table is 7 (as days of week) fields, and 5 rows deep.